# Compare value between Postgre Numeric with PHP variable

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a problem.

I store a number to Postgre database table named item:

```
id | quantity
1 | 10.55
```

id is integer, and quantity is numeric

And now i have a PHP variable like this :

$quantity = 10.55;

And then i retrieve quantity data from item table :

```
$sql = "select quantity from item where id = 1;";
```

And then cause i use CodeIgniter so i execute that query like this :

```
$res = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

And then i compare both of them like this :

```
if($res[0]['quantity'] != $quantity){
  echo(res[0]['quantity']." is different with ".$quantity);
}
```

And then the result is :

```
10.55 is different with 10.55
```

I stuck with it. Why 10.55 is different with 10.55 ?

Comment: Well it should work though, untill and unless ur not using "!==", it should work. try using floatval for both. like " if(floatval($res[0]['quantity']) != floatval($quantity)) "

Comment: @purushottam-zende : not worked for me. Any other idea ?

Comment: try putting the float value into mysql itself and chk, if record is returned then its same or else different.

Comment: add `var_dump($res[0]['quantity']);` line and tell what it shows

Comment: The code you've shown is not the code you're actually runing.